# Custom ubuntu install to enable wifi on inspiron-1501 w/o wired ethernet

Tags: ubuntu, wifi, system-installation

I am helping a small non-profit install ubuntu on some (40) donated inspiron's.  To get wifi running I need to install some additional packages:
      b43-fwcutter firmware-b43-installer.

I would like to create an install CD or USB stick that does not require a wired internet connection.  Unfortunately, the firmware-b43-installer seems to access the internet as part of its installation.  So even if I can figure out how to add these two packages to the install CD, I'm not sure this will help.

Anyone have an idea how I can accomplish this.  Thanks.

Comment: I installed uck (Ubuntu Customization Kit) and was able to build a customized kubuntu image.  It wrote to usb fine and I have wifi; however, only the guest user can login.  I get a message: "call to lnusertemp failed(temporary directories full?). Check your installation".  Similar behavior to that reported in http://askubuntu.com/questions/562797/problem-in-making-customized-kubuntu-livecd .

Comment: Most of the graphical tools for this are quite broken now. You could try the [manual method](http://askubuntu.com/a/49679/44179) though

Comment: There's also a workaround for the installer requiring an active internet connection: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2277779&p=13283442#post13283442

Comment: Catch 22. To get the internet connection I need wifi for which I need the new install disk

Comment: I'm working on the manual custom CD.  One confusion:  I have made the /etc/apt/source.list the same in the chroot & my machine;however, there are packages that I cannot find or install in the chroot that I have installed on this machine.  How can this be?

Comment: Can you provide an example of said packages? (like a package name or two)?

Comment: The first I noticed was b43-fwcutter which is needed for my wifi firmware.  It was found and installed with no problem on the machine itself.  I then had trouble installing synaptic - I had to use cut and paste, wget & dpkg to download and install the packages synaptic requires.

Comment: Resulting disk works as boot/install disk; however, while it has wifi enabled, networking is not properly configured.  Neither firefox nor synaptic can reach the internet without manual reconfiguration.   I will try manual process again.  This must be related to the problems I had working in the CHROOT above.